# Using Arduino to control a 12v car light system?

Tags: pwm, voltage-level, system-design

I am new, but I am wondering what options I may have to control a 12v line that connects to a light with Arduino i/o.

Given the voltage limitations of an arduino, I am thinking using some kind of 5v relay to switch a 12v line on/off ( if it exists )

Though I was also hoping to be able to utilize the PWM pins in conjunction with a 12v line to 'reduce' it to 6v without using a resistor.  (though I would have no idea how to go about this, or if it is even possible).

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use a relay. However, you'll almost certainly need to drive the relay with a transistor because the current requirements of the relay will be too high for an Arduino pin.

Better to use a logic MOSFET N-channel transistor as an electronic switch. You connect the Arduino's output pin to the gate of the transistor. You connect the + terminal of your 12 volt source to one end of the light, and connect the other wire from the light to the drain on the MOSFET. You then connect the source pin on the MOSFET to ground, and tie the ground of your Arduino to the 12 volt negative terminal.

In this setup, the MOSFET acts as a switch. When you switch the output pin of your Arduino to HIGH, the MOSFET turns on, providing a very low resistance path to ground. Current flows from the +12 volt supply, through the light, through the MOSFET, and to ground.

When the Arduino's output pin is low, the MOSFET acts as an open switch. There's no path to ground so the light is not lit.

You can't use PWM to lower 12 volts to 6 volts without some additional circuitry. PWM rapidly pulses the output from all the way on to all the way off. If you feed a PWM pin into a transistor, it can be used to create a higher voltage and/or current pulsed signal. However, pulsed DC is not the same thing as a lower DC voltage. You'd need to feed the pulsed 12 volts through a reservoir capacitor, perhaps 2 capacitors (and possibly a choke)  in order to average out the pulses into a lower DC voltage. That simple approach would work ok for powering a 6 volt incandescent light, but would not be good enough to power a solid state component because the output would not be even enough. It would have a fair amount of ripple and high frequency noise in it.

Comment: This is excellent thank you.  I've been studying transistors, but I think I need to study a bit more : )

re: PWM - I should have been more specific that these are LED lights.  It is a 12v line but the bulb itself has a few LEDs on it - (I'm not sure exactly how its internals are set up).  But it seems transistors are the way to go.

The goal with the PWM is to reduce brightness.

Comment: Okay. You can use PWM to reduce the apparent brightness of the LEDs. You still need to use the full voltage to calculate the current limiting resistor though (e.g. LED forward voltage = 1.2 volts. Supply voltage = 12 volts. desired LED current = 20 mA.  resistor value = (12-1.2)/.02= 540 ohms.Then PWM control varies the duty cycle of the LED, which changes the **apparent** brightness. (I say apparent because what really happens is the LED flashes between on and off too rapidly for our eyes to see, so our eyes average the total light output over time.)

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  This is perfect!  Project is actually for initially hooking up a microcontroller within my motorcycle to do various tasks.  I'll write up a tutorial sometime when it's completed.  Thanks again.

I suppose I have one last curiosity - is there any limitation on transistors when combined with PWM?  If a pwm is flashing at 50hz... is there any factor in limiting the transistor to 'keep up' ?

Comment: No, there shouldn't be. The whole reason for using PWM rather than varying the voltage is that transistors get hot when you run them in between on and off. One thing you should be aware of: Ardunio PWM runs at about 500 Hz. At that rate, if the lights are road lights, when you move across somebody's field of view what they will see is a trail of dots of light. It can be distracting. For that application you might want to put a properly rated capacitor between the + and ground leads to the LEDs to smooth out the output and eliminate the flashing.